# adding images along with text in listview in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which involves list along with images.can anyone tell how can i do this..

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this example might help you http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-part-2

Answer (score 1):

you can use this link.. i feel, this is the best example...
http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the documentation relating to [lists and adapters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html).

Possibly the easiest adapter to get acquainted with is [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Don't be afraid of the online documentation, it's really approachable once you get used to it.